# 405 (Method Not Allowed) for POST method in angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send a `POST` and `GET` requests from angular to .Net web api project GET requests works fine but when it comes to `POST` request it doesn't works it gives me following error ,

> OPTIONS http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/GetEvent 405 (Method
>   Not Allowed) Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/GetEvent' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

Bellow is my `POST` request,

In `component.ts`

```
 getDate() {
    let dateList: any = {};
    dateList.startDate = this.startDate;
    dateList.endDate = this.endDate;

    this._lkassetsService.getEventDetails(JSON.stringify(dateList)).subscribe((eventData: any) => {
        this.msg = eventData;    
     });
}
```

In `service.ts`

```
getEventDetails(dateList: any): Observable<any> {
   return this._http.post('http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/GetEvent', dateList, {
     headers:new HttpHeaders({ 
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     })
   });        
  }
```

Bellow is my .net web api request from backend

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/MyAttendance/GetEvent")]
public string Event([FromBody]object Text)
{

    return "Success";
}
```

This request worked fine with postman and in my `web.cong` file(.net web api) I have added bellow code,

```
   <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

And also if I use `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` instead of  `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` It worked fine but output would be null but I want out as `json` format

I have no idea about this problem I am very much appreciated If someone can help me. I saw many solutions but that did not work

Comment: Can you add the Asp.Net Controller of the Http Request?

Comment: You can use Angular Proxy : https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: You definitely need to enable CORS, and I'm not sure what you provide in the web.config will be sufficient.  Is this .NET core or .NET framework?

Comment: @GermanQuinteros I added the .net contoller request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue in my project. The way how I succeeded was by doing these changes on API side. (our .net framework version is 4.6.1)

in web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Cors-Origins" value="http://localhost:4200" />
  </appSettings>
```

in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
string origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cors-Origins"];
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, "*", "*") {SupportsCredentials = true});
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use the action name `GetEvent` use other than `get` for post method. if you use get in action name it becomes get  method